# Can Euler's totient function be used to decide primality?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

For $\phi(\cdot)$ being Euler's totient function and $n \in \mathbb N_{>1}$, let $S_a=\{n|\phi(n)=a\}$ and $T_a=\{n|n\ne (a+1),2(a+1) \land \phi(n)=a\}$. Plainly $T_a \subset S_a$, and $S_a = T_a \Rightarrow (a+1) \not \in \mathbb P$.

**My question is:** If we can in principle know $T_a$, can we decide whether $a+1 \in \mathbb P$?

By way of example, $T_{12}=\{21,28,36,42\}$ and $T_{24}=\{35,39,45,52,56,70,72,78,84,90\}$. In these simple cases, we know that $13$ is prime and $25$ is not prime, so $S_{12}=T_{12}+\{13,26\}$, but $S_{24}=T_{24}$. From a knowledge of the members of the sets alone, could we decide that $13$ is prime and $25$ is not?

Assume for some large even number $a$ we did not know whether $a+1$ was prime. In at least some (ideal?) instances, $a$ might be readily factorable such that it would be possible to compute many or all of the members of $T_a$. Under that assumption, is there any mathematical relationship or algorithm that would allow the primality of $a+1$ to be determined from a knowledge of $T_a$? Would a complete knowledge of $T_a$ be necessary, and if not, what fraction of the members of $T_a$ would suffice to determine the primality question?

Comment: Factoring and computing Euler's totient function are known to be equivalent for arbitrary numbers (see this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/3274/3959)). Seems like if you could "know $T_a$" for arbitrary $a$, that would be equivalent to knowing how to factor, in which case you might as well just go ahead and factor...

Comment: See also [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/31691/3959) about solving $\phi(m)=n$ given $n$.  And [this paper referenced there](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2006-75-254/S0025-5718-06-01826-6/home.html) shows that even knowing the factorization of $n$ there is no polynomial-time algorithm that gives all solutions to $\phi(m)=n$ in general.  From the abstract: "What this means it that the problem of deciding whether there even exista solution $m$ to $\phi(m)=n$, let alone finding all of them, is very likely to be intractable."

Comment: (By contrast, we have a [polynomial time deterministic primality testing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test), so it seems like this would not be a good fit or necessarily good approach.)

Comment: Of course we can, but perhaps not efficiently: Given a non-empty set $T$ and assume we know that this is $T_a$ for some unknown $a$, then we find $a$ by computing $\phi(n)$ for any $n\in T$, and then find out whether $a+1\in\Bbb P$ by trial division of $a+1$ by all $d\le\sqrt a$

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Thanks for the interesting and informative links.